# Task Manager is displaying incorrect memory for javafx application

Tags: java, windows

Windows task manager is displaying 350mb memory usage for my javafx application while Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() is 268mb (92 used+176 free). I am not able to understand this random behavior of task manager. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Someone correct me if I am wrong, but the JVM memory and Java Application memory are not the same. The JVM memory contains more than just heap memory.

Comment: If it is true then how do i find out total application usage? Even jprofiler displays same results

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375098/java-memory-usages

Comment: did you tried jvisualvm. you can find it in /jdk/bin/jvisualvm. it will show you heap usage.

Comment: Task Manager displays correct memory figures. What's wrong is your interpretation. By default, Task Manager shows the private [Process Working Set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684891.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

The Windows Task Manager shows the allocated memory for the entire Java Virtual Machine (JVM) running your JavaFX Application.

According to the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) totalMemory() only ...

> Returns the total amount of memory in the Java virtual machine.

The remaining 82MB seem to be allocated by the JVM itself and not your application.

Comment: The heap doesn't include; the JVM itself, code space, thread stacks, GUI native components, direct memory buffers or shared libraries. +1

Answer (score 0):

Windows task manager is not a good tool to observe memory consumption statistics for your java application.

Java memory basically contains two types of spaces :

1. Java heap space - where class instances and array objects are stored.
2. JVM memory(Non-heap memory) - It's created at JVM startup and contains method,field data,constants and native code.This data doesn't resides in heap space.This is reason you are getting different statistics in comparison of task manager.